# Excel VBA: Show/Hide Pictures on yes/no dropdowns; troubleshooting simultaneous .Visible?

Tags: excel, vba

Forgive me, I know nothing about VBA and I had the crazy idea to make Xmas presents that digitally replicate a scratch-off bucket list or novelogue poster in Excel. After lots of frustration, I got as far as being able to turn on/off a picture with an individual dropdown ("Unread"/"Complete"). It's a big table of book titles with book covers hidden until each one is marked Complete, then that book cover should display.

The problem is that only one image will show at a time. If two books are marked complete, only the most recent changed to Complete will be visible. Is this because I have them all running in the same Sub? Do I need a separate Sub for every image (that would be 100 Subs)?

Snippet, let's say there were only 5 books:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B4")) Is Nothing Then
        Shapes("Picture 1").Visible = Range("B4").Value = "Complete"
    Else
        Shapes("Picture 1").Visible = False
    End If
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D4")) Is Nothing Then
        Shapes("Picture 2").Visible = Range("D4").Value = "Complete"
    Else
        Shapes("Picture 2").Visible = False
    End If
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F4")) Is Nothing Then
        Shapes("Picture 3").Visible = Range("F4").Value = "Complete"
    Else
        Shapes("Picture 3").Visible = False
    End If
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H4")) Is Nothing Then
        Shapes("Picture 4").Visible = Range("H4").Value = "Complete"
    Else
        Shapes("Picture 4").Visible = False
    End If
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J4")) Is Nothing Then
        Shapes("Picture 5").Visible = Range("J4").Value = "Complete"
    Else
        Shapes("Picture 5").Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm sure there's some more efficient way to do this but I'm more concerned with getting the images to show independently of other images' visible values. Thanks!

EDIT: I'm sorry my explanation wasn't clear enough. I don't have enough reputation to share an image, unfortunately. There are 10 columns of book covers, and 10 rows. Every other column holds images (in between is spacer). See below for rows.

When marked "Unread" in the cell below, the image should be hidden. When marked "Complete" below, the image should be revealed.

To explain cell layout:

- B2 holds the image
- B3 holds the title
- B4 holds the data validated dropdown (that VBA checks for B2's image value of visible)

Spreadsheet layout:

- B2:T2 have the first 10 images and thus,
- B4:T4 have the first 10 data validated dropdowns
- B7:T7 next dropdowns
- B10:T10 " "
- B13:T13, then B16:T16, B19:T19, B22:T22, B25:T25, B28:T28, B31:T31

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zX5pV.jpg

Comment: In the example you've given, you seem to be using every second column on row 4 as where you've located your `individual dropdown`?  Is that the case, and are each of those cells a data validation cell?  Is that how you've organised your `big table`?

Comment: Yeah, it's just the way I set up the spreadsheet -- every other column has the book cover, below it the title, below it the data validated dropdown to trigger the book cover's visibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if I understood your question correctly but I tried just putting the repetitive parts of your code into a loop. Also, it will now not turn pictures invisible again.
If you are unfamiliar with the `Cells` property I used, you can find more information on it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.cells).

Also, I split up this piece of code:

```
Shapes("Picture 1").Visible = Range("B4").Value = "Complete"
```

How was that supposed to work? I guess you wanted the picture to be visible and the cell to show "Complete"...

The picture name inside the loop is created by string concatenation from `"Picture " & i`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i as Long
    Dim totalNumberOfPictures as Long

    totalNumberOfPictures = 8 'Input number of pictures you have here

    For i=1 To totalNumberOfPictures 
        If Not Intersect(Target, Cells(4, 2 * i)) Is Nothing Then
            Shapes("Picture " & i).Visible = True
            Cells(4, 2 * i) = "Complete"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Or if you meant every picture where the assigned cells value is changed to "Complete" should be visible, you can try this:
Edit: Updated to address the added detail in your question...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i as Long
    Dim totalNumberOfPictures as Long
    Dim count as Long
    Dim rowOffset as Long

    totalNumberOfPictures = 100 'Input number of pictures you have here
    count = 1
    rowOffset = 0
    For i=1 To totalNumberOfPictures 
        If Cells(4 +  rowOffset, 2 * count) = "Complete" Then
            Shapes("Picture " & i).Visible = True
        Else
            Shapes("Picture " & i).Visible = False
        End If
        If count = 10 Then   ' 10 is the number of pictures per "row"
            rowOffset = rowOffset + 3   ' 3 is the row difference between  your dropdown rows
            count = 0
        End if
        count = count+ 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

Let me know if it works, or if this is not what you meant, what you actually want...

Comment: Thanks for the very fast reply! I edited my initial post to better explain, and it looks like a link to a screenshot worked.

Using your second code but changed totalNumber to 100; images in B2:T2 respond, so the script is working for B4:T4. Is there a way extend the range of the cells in your If Cells() statement?

Comment: @Julie427 I updated the code in my answer. You have to set the number next to `totalNumberOfPictures = 100` (<-- here) to the total number of pictures you have in your worksheet...

Comment: Right, I changed it to 100 in my initial attempt. I've just tried your new snippet. I don't understand why but nothing below the first 10 books is responding as it should even with your new adjustments. Thanks!

Comment: I just noticed a mistake I made, try it now, I think it should work :)

Answer (score 0):

If it was my project, I’d do it a slightly different way.  I’ll offer this as a suggestion – let me know if it doesn’t suit you & I’ll delete it.

**Step 1** – rename the pictures to match the book titles.  This will be tiresome to start with, but it means you won’t be tied to a loop based on “Picture #” because picture names can vary.  Also makes the names more intuitive.

**Step 2** – copy the code below into a standard module &  run it when you’re on the sheet with the pictures.  It will create a named, non-contiguous range.  If you look at the code, it’s fairly obvious how you can adjust it over time to suit your changing needs.  Simply add more ranges as you need and rerun it.

```
Sub MakeRangeName()
ActiveSheet.Range _
("B4:T4,B7:T7,B10:T10,B13:T13,B16:T16,B19:T19,B22:T22,B25:T25,B28:T28,B31:T31") _
.Name = "myRange"
End Sub
```

**Step 3** – copy the code below to the Sheet code module where you have the pictures.  It will run whenever there’s a change in the range you created in Step 2, but will only affect the actual picture of interest.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo GetOut
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim s As String

If Not Intersect(Range("myRange"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    If ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0) = "" Then GoTo Letscontinue '<< to ignore the inbetween columns
    s = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Text
    If ActiveCell.Value = "Complete" Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(s).Visible = True
            Else
            ActiveSheet.Shapes(s).Visible = False
    End If       
End If

Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
GetOut:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

I’ve tested it and it works for me.  Let me know if you get stuck on anything.

Comment: Thank you for the work you've put into this. I already spent time renaming every picture in order of appearance, so I believe it would be reinventing the wheel to do so again.

You could leave this up for posterity -- maybe someone else could find it helpful? Searching around was how I was able to use any VBA code, after all.

Comment: I tested your two snippets without renaming the images (it didn't seem necessary to your code?), but when I try to change a dropdown value I get an error: "The item with the specified name wasn't found." I pasted the first snippet into Module 1, pasted the second snippet to the Sheet module, renamed the range to "covers" in both sections of code, then ran the macro in Excel. Is that wrong?

Comment: `The item with the specified name wasn't found` is because whichever cell you change via dropdown, the code looks at the cell above it - `s = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Text` - and then tries to find the image with that name.  Unfortunately, you do have to change the image names.  Try changing just the first image name & change the dropdown value & you'll see what I mean :)

Comment: Oh, yes, I see. I get it now. That does work, if I were to rename them all. Thanks again.

Comment: It wouldn't be as difficult as you think - just click on the cell with the book name, then in the formula bar highlight the name (excluding the single ') then click on the picture and copy the name you've highlighted into the name box.

Comment: Oh no, not difficult, just repetitive. I'm also making a movielogue so I think I'll try this method for it :). Thank you again for putting energy into solving a stranger's weird Excel problem!